# Git diff between feature branch and remote master branch

Tags: git

I'd need to compare the local changes of my feature branch with the remote upstream code.
My repository organization uses 'origin' to point to my master branch (fork of the remote upstream code).
And uses 'upstream' to point to the remote code.

```
origin  git@gitlab.acme:user1/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.acme:user1/project.git (push)
upstream        git@gitlab.acme:master/project.git (fetch)
upstream        git@gitlab.acme:master/project.git (push)
```

Here is the list of branches:

```
  7.x
* feature-branch
  remotes/origin/7.2.x
  remotes/origin/7.x
  remotes/origin/feature-branch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/7.x
  remotes/upstream/7.x
```

As my fork derives from 7.x (which is the master remote branch), I've tried with:

```
git diff feature-branch remotes/upstream/7.x
```

but I see differences between the feature branch and the remote master branch which shouldn't be.
Any idea what's wrong in the command?

Comment: Isn't the origin branch just a local copy of the branch as stored on the origin? I don't think this reaches out to the *actual* origin, you still have to fetch it first. Or I may be wrong :-)

Comment: origin is the fork of the upstream but it is not up to date. I'd like to compare the upstream and the feature-branch. When I've created the feature-branch I did a 'git reset upstream/master' so that the feature-branch was aligned with the upstream code

Comment: Maybe your local repo is out of date?  Try `git fetch upstream` followed by `git diff feature-branch remotes/upstream/7.x`